# Precise definition of the solution of a differential equation on a compact set (short question)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $f : (0,T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the differential problem $(DP)$ given by
$$ u^{\prime} (t) = f(u(t)), $$
$$ u (0) = u_0 .$$

What is the **precise** meaning of the following sentence:

*the function $v : [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ solves the differential problem (DP) on the compact interval $[0,T]$.*

It seems crystal clear, that this must imply the following points:

- $v(0) = u_0$.
- $v \in \mathcal{C}^{1}((0,T))$.
- It must hold, that $v^{\prime}(t) = f(v(t))$ for all $t \in (0,T)$

But what else is required?

In particular, what is supposed to happen at the boundaries $v(0)$ and $v(T)$ ?

Does $v$ have to be continuous on the whole compact interval $[0,T]$? It seems rather natural to at least require $v \in \mathcal{C}([0,T))$.

Is this sufficient, or do we need/want $v \in \mathcal{C}([0,T])$ as well? If so, why?

Comment: More: $v\in\mathcal{C}^1([0,T])$, where $v'(0)$ is interpreted as $v'_+(0)$ and $v'(T)$ is interpreted as $v'_-(T)$; and, $v'(t)=f(v(t))$ for all $t\in[0,T]$.

Comment: I do not think, that should be a necessary requirement for a reasonable solution concept though. As a counterexample consider the differential problem $u' = u/t + 1$ with $u(0) = 0$ on $[0,1]$. A very reasonable solution for this is $v(t) = t \text{ln}(t)$, but the derivative $v'$ cannot be extended to the boundaries of $[0,1]$.

Comment: $t=0$ is outside the domain of the RHS of the equation.

Comment: I am aware of that. But $t = 0$ is, however, in the closure of the domain of the RHS of the equation and the function $x\text{ln}(x)$ still seems like a very reasonable solution to the overall problem, which an applied scientist could easily accept as useful.

Comment: Notice that $f$ is a function whose independent variable is the **state** variable, not the time variable, so there is something wrong with the first line of your question. Further, even when you fix it, $u/t$ will not fit into the definition: it is a *nonautonomous* ODE.